# How to use Template Haskell to get the body of function?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Currently I'm trying to do a translation from a Haskell subset without having to deal with all the parsing, typechecking etc. issues. Documentation didn't help me to figure out a function to get the function's body (all the definitions) by its name.

Context for this call should look something like

```
fac 0 = 1
fac x = z * fac (x - 1)

getBody = ...

main = do
    x <- runQ $ getBody [| fac |]
    print x
```

Does anyone knows

1. whether there are some good and up to date docs on TH (not the reference on Hackage) or
2. how to make getBody?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `runQ` here? Pretty sure there's no way you're going to get the information you want trying to use TH at run-time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, the way to find the definition of something with TH is using the `reify` function. However:

- You [can't use `reify` at run-time](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell#Why_does_runQ_crash_if_I_try_to_reify_something.3F) via `runQ`. The information it needs is not available except during compilation.
- Currently, using `reify` to get function definitions is [not implemented due to lack of interest](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.8.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v%3aVarI) anyway.

Looks like you'll need to find another route. Have you considered using [the `haskell-src-exts` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) for parsing and/or the GHC API or something based on it?

Comment: Yes, we can't use reify at run-time, but we can use data it returns. It looks like this (mention this code needs to be split into 2 modules due to GHC stage restriction; also runs in GHCi):
`conv1 (TyConI x) = [| TyConI $(conv2 x) |]`
`conv2 (DataD _ name _ _ _) = [| DataD [] (mkName $(return $ LitE $ stringL $ show name)) [] [] [] |]`
`main = print $(reify ''Int >>= conv1)`

Also, `reify` would return AST for the _call_ of the function, but not it's body, anyway. There should be reifyDecl function, which is really absent.

I feel really grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: Using `reify` on the name of something generally does give you the declaration, when that makes sense--for a type it will give you the list of constructors, the `deriving` list, and so on. `reify`ing a function's name gives you a `VarI` for the info, which has a `Maybe Dec` value, i.e. a declaration. If I'm understanding what you want, `reify` would do it, it's just not implemented right now because apparently few other people want it.

Comment: To anyone who might read this: I'd be interested in working on this feature in the near future.  I could really use it.

Comment: @jtobin: See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1831 on the GHC Trac if you haven't already, I think that's talking about the same thing.

Comment: @jtobin Nice to hear that. I've sent you an email.